# Getting ASP:Menu to center in the middle of the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, menu, centering

I'm having a difficult time finding a solution to my problem that relates to `asp:Menu` control and centering in a page. I'm really surprised all the solutions I search on Google are either not using `asp:Menu` control or just using lists or tables only.

I know `margin:0` auto` and adding a width works but when I put it for the menu control I can't get it working.

This is my master page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div id="PageWrapper">
                <header></header>
                <nav>
                    <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false" DataSourceID="dsSiteMap" CssClass="MainMenu" />
                    <asp:SiteMapDataSource runat="server" ID="dsSiteMap" ShowStartingNode="false" />
                </nav>
                <section id="MainContent">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="cpMainContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </section>
                <footer></footer>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
    background-color: gray;
}

#PageWrapper
{
    width: 1366px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: auto;
}

nav
{
    width: 1366px;
    height: 36px;
    background-color: seagreen;
}

nav a
{
    color: #fff;
}

.MainMenu
{
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    width: 1366px;
    height: 19px;
    background-color: #555555;
}

ul.level1
{ 
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Sitemap:

```
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
    <siteMapNode url="~/">
        <siteMapNode url="~/Default.aspx" title="Home"  description="Go to the homepage" />
        <siteMapNode url="~/NewTicket.aspx" title="New Ticket"  description="Create a new ticket" />
        <siteMapNode url="~/Search.aspx" title="Search" description="Search tickets" />
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

Funny thing is when I create a label and place it in a placeholder, `margin: 0 auto` and `width: auto` works in centering.

Comment: try adding the properties to your menu's ID. in your case it "Menu1"

Comment: Like: 
#Menu1
{
    width: 1366px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
?
Still has it to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone.

I finally was able to figure it out.

I edited the styling to my nav parent element:

```
nav{
clear: both;
text-align: center;
display: table;
margin: 0 auto;}
```

So instead of having it displayed as a block I set it as a table. Funny thing is it is still rendered as a list.
I have it to clear because I have elements before it that was floated to the left.
I definitely learned a lot more about CSS with this issue.

Kind of crazy for so much trouble just for one styling. Surprised

Answer (score 0):

I don't remeber the generated markup for asp:menu but I think the problem is in your `.MainMenu` selector, you are defining it with `width: 1366px;` what maches the `nav` width, so even if you set margin-right/left auto it won't work.

To center it you can or you set a width smaller than its parent's or you can set `display: inline-block;` for the menu and `text-align:center;` in the nav.

Example for the two options: http://jsfiddle.net/T9SvT/

Comment: Thank you for the link, I see how it works, but then I took the same idea on my CSS: 
.MainMenu
{
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    background-color: #555555;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

However it still went to the left side, no change. I got rid of all CSS that had margin: 0 auto or display: block left over code just in case it was overriding. No go.

Comment: I checked out the source on my page as well. It shows style="float:left" on it. I'm not sure why it does. I never set that in CSS or my master.

Comment: Funny thing is, I write down clear: both on both in-line style and on CSS and the page completely ignores my code and still puts a float:left in the source.

Comment: The `float:left` do mess up with the centering. You're using the wrong property to "cancel" the `float:left`, it's not `clear:both` you should use `float: none`. I updated my example: http://jsfiddle.net/T9SvT/1/

Comment: No change. Also when I go to the debugger on Chrome (F12) it shows the float: none; property crossed out.

Comment: It's hard to tell you the correct approach, if it's crossed out it means it's being overriden by another float definition, if you have no access to that other definition you can use the !important: `float: none !important;`

Answer (score 0):

I duplicated your example above.  #PageWrapper is 1366px wide and centered on the page.  It contains the Menu control which is also 1366px wide and its cells are spaced evenly across the width.  I tested this in Chrome and IE9.  I only have 3 items in my sitemap, however.  That may be related to your problem: how wide is the menu?

Keep in mind that `asp:Menu` renders as an HTML table, so when you apply a style to it, that is basically what you are working with.  I would recommend sizing the `<nav>` area to where you want the Menu to be and simply making the Menu fill that space with Width="100%".

Certainly "float" should not be necessary.